# Why do iOS and Android versions of the Square Register SDK return different values?

Tags: android, square-connect

Our Android team has been integrating the Register SDK that was announced recently and has run into a couple of issues.

The first question is about the difference in the properties of the response objects passed back in iOS and Android. In iOS, the callback URL’s `data` parameter includes the `transaction_id` and `offline_payment_id` fields. However, in Android the `ChargeRequest.Success` object has the properties `clientTransactionId` and `serverTransactionId`.

Can anyone explain how we should interpret this variance between the SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for identifying out-of-date information in the documentation. The `payment_id` and `offline_payment_id` fields returned by the Register API on iOS are now  **deprecated**.

On Square Register 4.42 and later, the Register API on iOS returns `transaction_id` and `client_transaction_id` fields that you should use instead. These correspond to the `serverTransactionId` and `clientTransactionId` fields that are returned by the Register SDK on Android.

Be sure to update your Square Register app to ensure that you receive these new values in your response.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful, but what are the semantics of these parameters? Should we be saving them? Will they help to identify transactions or diagnose problems later? What about the old `payment_ids`? Does one or both of the new parameters map to the old ones? Thanks!

Comment: Per Square, "Transaction" and "Payment" are different types with different semantics. Since the distinction isn't reflected in the Register SDK, they have settled on using Transactions only, and there is no way to map earlier stored payment IDs to transaction ID values.